# User Authentication in rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When trying to use user authentication I get the following error: "NoMethodError in Viewer#show". And it addresses the error to `<%= @page.body.html_safe%> in app/views/viewer/show.html.erb:1:in '_app_views_viewer_show_html_erb__685858346_34780128'`, which is only one line code by now.

But, when I call login page on browser address bar like: `:3000/session/new`, it comes Up. Which is not happening  with `:3000/session/destroy`.

It seems that something related to the route is not working properly because, on the other hand, when I call a page on `views/layouts/application.htm.erb` like `<li><%= link_to 'Home', {:controller => 'viewer', :action => 'show', :name => 'home'} %></li>` it works, and if I switch to `<li><%= link_to 'Home', view_page_path('home') %></li>` it gives a similar error.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Can you show a little more of your controller code that leads to this one line view? The `view_page_path('home')` looks odd to me. I thought `view_page_path` expected an object, such as `view_page_path(@home)`, not a string or symbol.

Comment: also show your routes `rake routes`

Comment: <li><%= link_to 'Home', {:controller => 'viewer', :action => 'show', :name => 'home'} %></li>
     <li><%= link_to 'Resources', {:controller => 'viewer', :action => 'show', :name=>'resources'} %></li>
     <li><%= link_to 'Services', {:controller =>'viewer', :action => 'show', :name=> 'services'} %></li>
     <li><%= link_to 'About Us', {:controller => 'viewer', :action => 'show', :name=> 'about'} %></li>
     <li><%= link_to 'Contact Us', {:controller => 'viewer', :action => 'show', :name=> 'contact'} %></li>
     
    </ul>
    <div>
  
  <div id='footer'>

Comment: The same code above was supposed to be optimized using path, like: "<li><%= link_to 'Home', view_page_path('home') %></li>"

Comment: get "/:name" => 'viewer#show'
  resources :pages 
  resources :users
  resource :session
  
  match ':name' => 'viewer#show' 
  
  match 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login
  match 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
  match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup
  
  get "pages/home"

  get "pages/resources"

  get "pages/services"

  get "pages/about"

  get "pages/contact"

Comment: at the end root :to => 'viewer#show', :name => 'home'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `view_page_path('home')` assumes that there is a named path `view_page`. Changing

```
get "/:name" => 'viewer#show'
```

to

```
get '/:name' => 'viewer#show', :as => :view_page
```

should fix that.

Secondly when using route helpers with named parameters you need to specify the name so Rails knows what parameters should be used. Change `view_page_path('home')` to `view_page_path(:name => 'home')`.

And finally a NoMethodError for `<%= @page.body.html_safe%>` suggests to me that either `@page` or `@page.body` is nil.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It works! The only problem I'm having is how to call user login. Any progress I'll let you know. Thanks once again.